# Extending a 2.4GHz router using a 5GHz router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My ISP provided an Optic Fibre router that is an old model and provides Wifi at 2.4GHz only. I also have a secondary TP-Link router (Archer D7) lying around which has both 2.4 and 5GHz Wifi bands. Is it a good idea to connect the two routers using cable and then turn off ISP router's Wifi and use D7's Wifi to get 5GHz bandwidth? Are pitfalls that I should be looking for? How should I connect the two routers; using LAN port to LAN port or WAN to LAN?

I have done some homework and I understand that 5GHZ band has less penetration and shorter range. In my case these things are not a problem since all my machines are in a single room.

And while we are at it, would a 5GHz connection outperform a standard wired connection?

Comment: Hi @dotNET can the ArcherD7 do both 2.4 and 5G simultaneously? [lots can't even if they support both bands].  Will it outperform - possibly but also possibly not (because many things can impact it).  Try turning the router 90deg or put on it's side and see how it impacts performance ..

Comment: Yes, D7 supports both bands at the same time. I'm still trying to figure out a way to objectively measure the speed difference between the two modes, Unfortunately all wifi speed tests (e.g. ookla and fast) appear to measure Internet download and upload speeds, not my local (LAN) data transfer speed, which is already bottlenecked by my connection speed and is therefore not going to get any benefit from 5GHz band. Looks like my only option is to do a manual file copying operation over both bands and see. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely better off connecting LAN to LAN and disabling the DHCP server on the Archer router (because this will reduce double NAT issues). You will likely also want you configure the Archer to be in the same subnet as the main LAN (but not the same ip as the router)

If everything is in close proximity as you suggest you will likely get better performance on ghe 5 gig band as its less congested and less prone to interference as a redult - and as a result of the lesser penetration.

The downside is that if you have devices in other rooms (like cellphones/tablets) they will not work as well  There is likely little dusadvantage to leaving the 2.4 gig band active and on a dufferent SSID, which is the best of both worlds

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Success. I have connected my Archer D7 to my Optic Fiber router through LAN ports and turned on 5GHz band on Archer, while leaving the 2.4GHz band of Fiber router working. I now get around 8-9MBps on 5GHz band when doing large file copying in Windows, as opposed to around 1 MBps that I get on 2.4GHz band. My Ethernet cable connections give me around 11MBps speed, so 5GHz is not that bad. Not sure if this is the speed that I should be getting on an 802.11ac connection, but it is much better than 2.4GHz anyway.